# How to convert a one variable list chart in plot into ggplot2 format?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm searching but still can't find an answer to a quite simple question - how can we produce a simple line plot of one variable with ggplot2 in R?

I'm analyzing a time series data and I want to do more complex manipulation of my chart. I think it will be better if I use ggplot2 instead of `plot()`.

It works well with plot() function, but how do I use that column in ggplot2?
[image]
**Working solution in plot**

list dput output:

```
structure(c(51.846, 44.508, 41.244, 48.568, 46.714, 44.986), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "America/New_York", tzone = "America/New_York", index = structure(c(1392406020, 
1392406320, 1392406620, 1392406920, 1392407220, 1392407520), tzone = "America/New_York", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), .Dim = c(6L, 1L))
```

Code:

```
plot(res$s, type="n", main=title)
    print(lines(res$s))
```

Data:

```
                      [,1]
2014-02-14 14:27:00 51.846
2014-02-14 14:32:00 44.508
2014-02-14 14:37:00 41.244
2014-02-14 14:42:00 48.568
2014-02-14 14:47:00 46.714
2014-02-14 14:52:00 44.986
```

**Failed Approach in ggplot2**

Code:

```
p <- ggplot(data = df$s) +  geom_line(data =df$s)
print(p)
```

Dataframe:

```
                         s       window           
2014-02-14 14:27:00 51.846         864         
2014-02-14 14:32:00 44.508         864        
2014-02-14 14:37:00 41.244         864         
2014-02-14 14:42:00 48.568         864       
2014-02-14 14:47:00 46.714         864         
2014-02-14 14:52:00 44.986         864
```

dput output:

```
    structure(list(s = c(51.846, 44.508, 41.244, 48.568, 46.714, 
    44.986), window_size = c(864L, 864L, 864L, 864L, 864L, 864L)),
 .Names = c("s", "window_size"), row.names = c("2014-02-14 14:27:00", "2014-02-14 14:32:00", 
    "2014-02-14 14:37:00", "2014-02-14 14:42:00", "2014-02-14 14:47:00", 
    "2014-02-14 14:52:00"), class = "data.frame")
```

> Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric

PS>  res is a list. I have casted that list into a data frame, because that's the class ggplot2 uses.

Comment: what are your columns in `df`?

Comment: can you please use `dput()` to create data we can reproduce

Comment: `ggplot(dfr aes(x = seq_len(nrow(dfr)), y = s)) + geom_line()` is crude but works.

Comment: @JackBrookes thanks for asking about dput output. I didn't know it existed. It is very useful.

Comment: So the values in column `s` are what? Looks like the time and a value. e.g. should `2014-02-14 14:27:00 51.846` be split into `2014-02-14 14:27:00` and `51.846`

Comment: Can you `dput` part of your original list?

Comment: Just added it to the original question. I tried todo that, but I had to convert it to text to then apply regex? It seems to me there might be an easier workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are working with data from the `xts` package, which was not clear. First, we should convert your `xts` style data to a normal dataframe that `ggplot2` can use. `ggplot2` has a function `fortify` for this. Then you can plot the two columns with `ggplot` by mapping them to `x` and `y` aesthetics as normal.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(xts)

res <- structure(c(51.846, 44.508, 41.244, 48.568, 46.714, 44.986), class = c("xts", 
                                                                                 "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                                                          "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "America/New_York", tzone = "America/New_York", index = structure(c(1392406020, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    1392406320, 1392406620, 1392406920, 1392407220, 1392407520), tzone = "America/New_York", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(6L, 1L))
mydata <- fortify(res) # converts to dataframe for ggplot use

ggplot(mydata, aes(x = Index, y = res)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  labs(x = "Time")
```

[image]

Here's what `mydata` looks like:

```
                Index    res
1 2014-02-14 14:27:00 51.846
2 2014-02-14 14:32:00 44.508
3 2014-02-14 14:37:00 41.244
4 2014-02-14 14:42:00 48.568
5 2014-02-14 14:47:00 46.714
6 2014-02-14 14:52:00 44.986
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not mention xts package. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: This can be done without converting to data frame like this: `autoplot(res) + labs(x = "Time")`