# How to convert plot to ggplot in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am new to R and I am trying to convert plot to ggplot.

```
plot(res$s, type="n", main=title)  
print(lines(res$s))
```

`res$s` output

```
2014-02-14 51.8460                                                         
2014-02-14 44.5080
```

Comment: You can't convert a plot object to a ggplot object. But you can use `ggplot` instead of `plot` in your code. What have you tried so far? Can you give us a [mcve]?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49590999/how-to-convert-a-one-variable-list-chart-in-plot-into-ggplot2-format/49591415?noredirect=1#comment86202179_49591415

Comment: @kKenny Can you expand on this? What is your intended output vs actual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot "convert" a graphic from base R to ggplot2. You have to replot the data. ggplot2 provides the function `qplot()`that has a syntax similar to `plot()`.

If you have a two column dataframe: df$x and df$y,

```
qplot(df$s,df$y, geom='line')
```

should do what you want.

Answer (score 9):

Using package ggplotify:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplotify/vignettes/ggplotify.html

```
library(ggplotify)
res<-read.table(text="
s
\"2014-02-14 51.8460\"                                                         
\"2014-02-14 44.5080\" ", header=T)  
p <- as.ggplot(function() plot(res$s, type="n", main="title")  )
p
```

Comment: perfect thanks.  I tried this with a number of packages and they all seem to work.